# Fundamental solution of heat equation with time dependent diffusion coefficient

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, fundamental-solution

Consider the heat equation

$$ u_{t} = k(t) \Delta u + f(t,x),~~x \in \mathbb{R}^{n},t>0 $$
$$ u(0,x) = u_{0}(x). $$

If $k(t) = k$, then

$$ u(t,x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\phi(x-y,kt)u_{0}(y)dy + \int_{0}^{kt} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\phi(x-y,kt-\tau)f(y,\tau) d \tau dy $$
where
$$
\phi(x,t) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{(4 \pi t)^{\frac{n}{2}}}e^{-\frac{|x|^{2}}{4t}} & t>0 \\
0 & t<0.
\end{cases}
$$
But if $k$ is time dependent on $t$ (I am assuming $k(t)$ is sufficiently smooth function) then is it possible to find solution?

It might be an easy question, but I am not getting any idea, how to solve it. Any reference would also be welcome.

Comment: Well, you can change variables: $t(s) = \int_0^s k^{-1}(s') ds'$, and $v(x, s) = u(x, t(s))$.

Comment: Thanks, I hope it is similar to say that $s  = \int_{0}^{t}k(\tau) d\tau$